# 3d maze recursion method - c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, methods, recursion, maze

I am making a 3D maze in c++. I am having trouble with a recursive method to find a valid path between the two endpoints (starting point is m[0][0][0]; endpoint is m[7][7][7];). It checks positions in the array. If its contents are a 1, then it is a valid part of the path; if 0, it is not a valid part of the path. Here is my method:

```
bool Maze::findPath(int row, int column, int level,string path){
cout << "findPath " << row << ", " << column << ", " << level << " value " << m[row][column][level] << endl;
if(row < 0 || row > 7 || column < 0 || column > 7 || level < 0 || level > 7 ){
    cout << "Out of bounds" << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    return false;
}
else if(m[row][column][level] == 0){
    cout << "spot is zero" << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    return false;
}
else if(visited[row][column][level] == 1){
    cout << "visited" << endl;
    return false;
}
else if(row == 7 && column == 7 && level == 7 && m[row][column][level] == 1){
    cout << "Found!" << endl;
    //system("PAUSE");
    return true;
}
else{
    visited[row][column][level] = 1;
    //cout << "searching..." << endl;
    if(row < 7 && findPath(row + 1,column,level,path))
        return true;
    if(column < 7 && findPath(row,column + 1,level,path))
        return true;
    if(level < 7 && findPath(row,column,level + 1,path))
        return true;
    if(row > 7 && findPath(row - 1,column,level,path))
        return true;
    if(column > 7 && findPath(row,column - 1,level,path))
        return true;
    if(level > 7 && findPath(row,column,level - 1,path))
        return true;
}
return false;
```

}

So the method checks for "Out of bounds", an invalid spot on the path (zero), a visited location. I'm not sure what exactly I'm missing, but the method returns true to mazes that are unsolvable. Can anybody see some blatant mistake that I may be missing with my recursive call? Thanks

EDIT: Fixed a few code mistakes, but it still seems to be "solving" unsolvable mazes.

Here's an example of a solvable maze that it is saying is not possible to solve:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1
```

Comment: Wait, is it solving unsolvable mazes or not solving solvable ones? Or both?

Comment: Here's a version that works, in case it helps :) http://ideone.com/mIW6eY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a problem in the `findPath(++row,column,level,path)` (and similar recursive calls): you don't want the variable increments to carry over to the other recursive calls. (For example, the variable `row` in `findPath(row,++column,level,path)` would be affected by the first recursive call.)

Use `findPath(row + 1,column,level,path)` (and similar) instead.

Also, in the last three recursive calls, you're not making the right tests:

```
//instead of level < 7
if(level < 7 && findPath(--row,column,level,path)) //should be row > 0
    return true;
if(level < 7 && findPath(row,--column,level,path)) //should be column > 0
    return true;
if(level < 7 && findPath(row,column,--level,path)) //should be level > 0
    return true;
```

EDIT

However, you don't actually need these tests since you filter out `out of bounds` errors at the top of your recursive function. Therefore, these calls can be simplified to:

```
return  findPath(row + 1,column,level,path) || findPath(row,column + 1,level,path)
          || findPath(row,column,level + 1,path) || findPath(row - 1,column,level,path)
          || findPath(row,column - 1,level,path) || findPath(row,column,level - 1,path);
```

Additionally, the test `&& m[row][column][level] == 1` is redundant since the `else if(m[row][column][level] == 0)` takes care of that. (I'd check `m[7][7][7]` before even calling this function the first time, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still having the same issue. In addition, making your suggested change makes the out of bounds test fail. Why do I not want the increment to carry over?

Comment: You don't want the increment to carry over because then you won't be testing unit steps in each direction; you'd be taking diagonal steps, staying in place, or doing other weird things. :)

Comment: Bless you! I didn't notice they were all "level" testing. Thank you so much!

Comment: As soon as my reputation is high enough, I'll upvote that answer! Thanks again!

Comment: @user1732610 You're welcome :) I'm pretty sure you can accept the answer, though (if you feel like this answer solves the problem, of course).

Comment: @user1732610 However, I don't think this level test error is too important as you filter out of bounds at the top of the recursive function.

Comment: It still seems to be "solving" unsolvable mazes. I'm not sure how it's getting to the other endpoint. I don't think it's making diagonal jumps. I'm currently looking at that.

Comment: Could you give an example of a simple unsolvable maze for which the program is wrong?

Comment: @user1732610 Could there possibly be an error while reading in the data? (print the `m` array to see if it's what you expect)

Comment: I don't think there's any error while reading in the data. I've done some cout-s to verify. I've included an example maze above that's failing. I'm not sure how helpful it will be. I'm looking right now to see where in the maze it is failing.

Comment: You've helped me out tons and steered me in a better direction. I'm going to verify your answer. Thanks for the tremendous help.

Comment: @user1732610 Oh, it seems that you still didn't have the correct tests: `row > 7`, `level > 7`, and `level > 7` should be `row > 0`, etc. I'd just take them all out as in my edit.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and got rid of those. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just Finished this algorithm as an assignment for a class, ours only used a 5x5 block as the maze, but I found that it will go very slowly testing all possibilities each time it reaches the block from any angle, I found that the program can be sped up significantly by setting values in your array to 0 as you determine that they're not useful.  I did it at the `return false` at the end of the function.